# Traffic from Adwords has a near-100% bounce rate

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, bounce-rate, google-dfp

With most web traffic sources, my bounce rates are unextraordinary. But with traffic coming from Google Adwords advertisements (googleads.g.doubleclick.net), the bounce rate is 100% most days, and very near 100% on the few remaining other days.

I triple-checked that my ads contain the correct url, and they contain content that matches the content of the website.

Has anyone else noticed anything like this? Could it be clickbots or something? I know it's not the best-designed site on the internet, but I don't think there's any way it merits a 100% bounce rate...right? Especially considering that traffic from other sources is much lower.

---

I got all this information by creating segments on Google Analytics based on traffic source. The average number of users per day is easily high enough to make these numbers significant.

Comment: Check if the analytics code appears twice or more.

Comment: @VergilPenkov No, it definitely appears only once.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that the keywords you are targeting are also catching people who are searching for them in another context. They then click your ad, see the contents have no relevancy to them, and leave.

In Google Analytics, go to Acquisition > AdWords> Search Queries.

Here you can see what people are searching that brings up your ads. You could find the weirdest things. If so, make use of the "Negative Keywords" functionality in AdWords which prevents the ad from showing to people who search for those words.

Essentially you are being more specific in your targeting, which should result in better quality leads clicking on your ads.

Answer (score 1):

First, lets define what 100% bounce rate is:

**Bounce rate of 100% means the person who clicked on your ad only visited the target landing page and did not go to any other page or perform any other actions.** So people are visiting your site but they are not engaging with the landing page.

This is very common and the only way to improve is to optimize your landing pages for conversion. Have a strong CTA, compelling copy and most importantly product/service people are interested in.

Also, make sure that your Ad copy is not misleading. People can read one thing in the ad and see something completely irrelevant on your target landing page.